# CSS3 onclick animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to learn the basics of CSS3 animation and onclick events but I'm stuck.

I want to use button id="3" to start the animation,  the red square as you as can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/4swmegpn/
And button id="4" to stop/reset the animation of the red square.

I just don't know where to start. I've started with adding onclick to:

```
<button id="button1" onClick=""> > </button>
```

But after that I can't come up with what to do. Something to call and activate "keyframes example" from the css-file, but not sure how to.

Comment: "I've started with adding onclick" and "Only CSS please, no JS or Jquery". You can't toggle animation states with `<button>` elements without JS. You could use the checkbox `:selected` hack though...

Comment: Oh, how do I toggle the animation then?

Comment: If I use javascript. How may I proceed then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add and remove class to the element to start / end animation. And in CSS add animation to that class (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tikosar/4swmegpn/1/)).
Also it is a good practice not to include any javascript code in HTML (like onclick you had), but rather add event listeners in scripts:

```
document.getElementById('startAnim').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('red').classList.add('animate');
});

document.getElementById('stopAnim').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('red').classList.remove('animate');
});
```

You can also use checkbox, hover state or other selectors to toggle animation from within CSS.
There are lots of techniques. It all depends on what you need to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I typed it also in the comment above, I tried both of you codes but nothing happens when I'm onclick. Do i need apache to run javascript on localhost?

Comment: You're welcome. You don't need to type anything. Just follow the fiddle link. I have edited the code.
If you want to serve your pages through HTTP, you need Apache, whether you use javascript in your pages or not. You can also open html documents through "file://" scheme, i. e. just double click the html file in your file browser, it should open it in the default web browser.

Comment: Could you help me once again please?:)

Now im trying to rotate the blue square whenever you hit the ">" key. But I can't get it to move. Im using the same principles as you showed me with the red square. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arkt3huv/

Comment: You're doing everything right, but there is a little mistake: on line 2 of js it should be `...classList.add('rotateright')` not `rotateright1`, since that's the class name you use in your CSS. And then `...classList.remove('rotateright')`.
BTW, you don't need to use `DOCTYPE`, `<head>` etc in jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes, that made wonders! Now, the last thing. I would like to rotate the blue cube 120degrees to the right when hitting >. The thing is, it returns to it's primal form after it have rotate. Also, I can only click once, then the buttons sort of lock itself. The same goes if you hit the < but then the blue cube rotates 120degrees to the left.

Comment: When animation is completed, the element reverts to its previous state, except for when `animation-fill-mode` is set to `forwards` or `both`, in which case it retains its final state described by the animation.
In your example, after the animation is done, you need to remove the class and then add it again when needed (using JS).
I would strongly advise you reading the specs of both [CSS Animations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/) and [CSS Transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) to fully understand the way they work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some pointers before we start talking about the animation

- You don't need to type `doctype` and also `head`, and `body` tags because the jsfiddle platform do it for you.
- It is good practice to escape `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` because they can break your HTML code.
- For CSS3 stuff like the animations it is good practice to use **Vendor Prefixes**, this are browser-specific prefixes that will enable the behavior you are looking for in that browser. Currently there are:

  1. Chrome & Safari: -webkit-
  2. Firefox: -moz-
  3. Opera: -o-
  4. Internet Explorer: -ms-

It is a good practice to leave the non-prefixed CSS3 code for last because it will override all browser-specific stuff above it. So here is an example of what your key-frames should look like:

```
@-webkit-keyframes tutsFade { /* your style */ }
@-moz-keyframes tutsFade { /* your style */ }
@-ms-keyframes tutsFade { /* your style */ }
@-o-keyframes tutsFade { /* your style */ }
@keyframes tutsFade { /* your style */ }
```

Now on the animation part - I've created a simplified version of your example here - https://jsfiddle.net/a1d1Lk6f/
What is new is the `.exampleAnimation` class that contains all you need for an element to start animating with the `example` animation defined at the bottom of the CSS file. You can add this class directly to an HTML element or control it form JavaScript to start/stop the animation.

Here are some basic tutorials for beginners: [Introduction to CSS Animation](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-introduction-to-css-animation--cms-21068), [Control CSS3 Animations With jQuery](http://amitd.co/blog/control-css3-animations-with-jquery).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Now, do I need apache to see the run javascript or? Because it won't work when Im testing.
Edit: When im testing the code from dreamweaver*

Comment: You can save the page locally and run it in your browser, but I don't think you can run it in the Dreamweaver designer view itself. You can also check the Console tab in the browser `Developer tools` for any errors. 
You also might want take a glance trough the beginner guide for stackoverflow and get familiar with how it works.